# How do I get date column from nsepy get-history function

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, nsepy

I am not able to get this date column which is visible in the below given image.[image]

I want to store this date in another dataframe

I have tried this:

```
sbin['Date']
```

but its not working

complete code:

```
from datetime import date
import datetime
from nsepy import get_history
import pandas as pd

enddate = datetime.datetime.today()
startdate = enddate - datetime.timedelta(10)
sbin = get_history(symbol='SBIN',
                   start=startdate,
                   end=enddate)
print(type(sbin))
sbin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#You are trying to access pandas.core.internals.BlockManager. So in order to get date you need to get the block manager first and then get the axis :

```
Bm = sbin._data
date_time = Bm.axes[1] 
print(date_time)
#if you want to access individual element access like a list
date_time[0]
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date
data = get_history(symbol="SBIN", start=date(2015,1,1), end=date(2015,1,31))
data[['Close']].plot()
```

ref: https://nsepy.xyz/